# The Ubuntu Developer Summit is coming up, what goals should we set for Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, community, ubuntu-community

we usually have some sessions at UDS to talk about AU and work on stuff. So far we have these 2 proposed sessions, one general one, and one specifically looking at integration:

- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/community-q-askubuntu
- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/community-q-askubuntu-integration

We have a [list of things](https://trello.com/board/ask-ubuntu/4ec557e6ea86c7153d127fc5) on the Trello board we have been working on. If there's any topic you'd like to see addressed please add an answer and we'll add it to the agenda.

I'll publish remote participation details when I have them so people can join in.

Answer (score 6):

### Session notes

Session is on Wednesday 17:05..18:00 PDT

- [`#ubuntu-uds-room-202` on Freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu-uds-room-202)
- [Live audio stream of the session room](http://icecast.ubuntu.com:8000/room-202.ogg.m3u)
- [Collaborative session notes etherpad](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-q/meeting/20396/community-q-askubuntu/) (join the [`~ubuntu-etherpad` team](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-etherpad/) to view/edit)

Other random agendas:

- Jorge "anti-bug reports" vs. Chipaca "well not exactly" showdown.

Comment: SHOWDOWN OF THE CENTURY